# Recieving notifications from APNs in iPhone applicationg without provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

Task:

- have a jailbroken iPhone
- need to write an application which would receive notifications from APNs

Problem: after running the application on iPhone program shows an error: "no valid apps-environment entitlement string found for application" (at registerForRemoteNotificationTypes- call i suppose).
As I've understood the problem source is that I built the application without a provisioning profile.

Question: is there any possibility to make the program work before I receive my apple developer account (in order to create a provisioning profile)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple Push Notification Service requires that a device be registered with the service in order to receive notifications. In order to register with the APNS server, an app needs to be signed and provisioned.

Also, jailbroken phones may not work correctly in many cases where a legitimate application, that has been signed, provisioned and distributed officially via the iTunes App Store, is being used.

I believe it was reported that notifications from the AIM app intended for legitimate iPhone users were being sent to people with jailbroken iPhones, who in some cases didn't even have AIM installed. This probably has something to do with the fact that jailbreaking allows a user to change their device's UDID, which just screws everything up.

Comment: *"Jailbroken phones may not work correctly in many cases where a legitimate application."* it has been fixed long ago. *"jailbreaking allows a user to change their device's UDID, which just screws everything up."* Irrelevant, the device token is totally different from the UDID.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You need to have a valid provisioning profile.

Answer (score -1):

You can send a **fake** push notification **locally** if you installed MobileSubstrate, with this method:

http://networkpx.blogspot.com/2009/06/sending-push-notification-locally.html

Comment: Whats the difference between local notification and a fake push notification? or that just a way to to hook, so code an be executed when notification received?